# Moderate raster values based on another raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, map-algebra

I am trying to make a soil erosion risk model using raster overlay in ArcGIS Pro.

I have calculated soil erosion risk in raster calculator by combining the following risk factor rasters:

1. slope
2. soiltype
3. rainfall

The risk from these factors is calculated based on the following table:

[image]

From this I derived 5 risk rasters which have been reclassified as follows:

slight-1

lower-2

moderate-3

high-4

very high-5

I have then added these into a new raster to make a risk model (values ranging 1-5):

[image]

The next step requires this model to be moderated based on a landcover raster(with risk categories ranging from 0 to 4)

The relationship of the risk values in these two rasters is determined by the following table:

[image]

What operation is required in raster calculator to achieve this result?

Following the last answer here is what I have after multiplying the original risk layer by 10 and then creating a new raster adding (+) the multiplied risk layer to the land category layer:

[image]

I then reclassify as per the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

This however seems to not change the risk categories compared to the original risk layer, as the count and location of pixels is identical between the 2 layers, so there has been no moderation of a class 5 to class 3 based on the land category layer if this makes sense, I must be doing something wrong here, could you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Just use Combine tool, it designed for this task.

Comment: You are almost there you are running the tool correctly, just not apply the correct values.  So looking at your Table 4, a very high erosion (5) moderated by a land cover risk of (2) should calculate out as a pixel value of "52", that recodes to the matrix value of "Moderate" which if as I have assumed is following the erosion class is 3. Now look what you have type into the reclassify tool for "52", you just typed in 5 for the new value, so you are not moderating the new value.  A matrix value for example of "21" should now be 1, but you have entered 2.. and so on.

Comment: Right! cause the new classes prior to reclassifying are all the possible combinations between the 2 layers.. it does make sense now I'll try reclassifying again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trick I have used in the past to answer this sort of question is to [multiply](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/times.htm) your erosion risk layer by 10 so you have values 10,20,30,40 & 50.  You then [add](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/plus.htm) your land cover raster to this raster. So a value of 32 for example is a moderate erosion/LC risk 2 combination.  Then run this raster through a [reclassify](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/reclassify.htm) tool and for example you would convert a 14 value back to 3 (moderate).

Having seen @FelixIP comment the [Combine](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/combine.htm) tool does the first two steps I suggested in one step which is undoubtedly much faster!  You would still need to reclassify the output if you want the same range of values as in your table.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer.. I have tried this but after reclassifying I am getting the same pixel values as in the original risk layer.. am I reclassifying incorrectly? I converted everything in the 10 range to 1, 20s to 2, 30s to 3 etc

Comment: Would that not be what you want? The Table 4 matrix value happens to be the same names as the erosion risk categories. So very high erosion which is value 5 is converted to a 3 if the land cover risk is 1 or 2?

Comment: Hi again,.. yes, converting that 5 to a 3 would be what I want but I don't seem to have done that, as what was 5 in the original layer is still 5 in the final reclassified one. so I must be reclassifying it wrong I guess

Comment: Sounds like it :) Typically you would update your question with an update section to expand on the issue, in this case how exactly are you running the reclassify tool? A screen shot would help.

Comment: yep just added the screenshot let me know if you need more!